# Mystery Film, TV-Film, Episode or Miniseries. Council elders speak through a vocoder

Tags: tv, story-identification

I'm trying to recall a show (film?) about a couple trapped in a mysterious city, town or village that is run by cloaked, hooded, and masked figures in red & black outfits.

The years in which this could have been made are from 1977-1992 but most likely I watched this between 1983-1986.

There may or may not have been a scene of motorcycle/s chasing a pick-up (or vice-versa) through a mountain tunnel.

One interesting feature is that the the leader of the council (and other council members) spoke through an old vintage classic analog [vocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocoder)...such as the one used for the voices of the Cylon Centurions in the original-series version of Battlestar Galactica.

(*The vocoder could be any of the following: Bode, EMS, Korg, Moog, Roland, Sennheiser or Synton. This could not have been made before 1977 since none of these vocoders was out before that (although the vocoder has been around since 1928, but not like the one in this film). The only ones that were were the EMS Vocoder 5000, the Moog Prototype Vocoder, and the one used in Colossus: The Forbin Project...but I doubt this was any one of those. I'm sure this was made after both BSG and Galactica 1980.*)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheOmniscientCouncilOfVagueness

Comment: Do you recall the genre of movie? Sci-fi, horror, fantasy?

Comment: I'm guessing that it's sci-fi and maybe possibly post-apocalyptic as well. Unfortunately I only saw one or two scenes from this.

Comment: Council elders speak through "vocoder", NOT "vocorder"!!

Comment: This question [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151027094903/http://watchfreetvseries.com/mid-80s-tv-film-with-vocoder/) contains a large list of films that it **isn't** _(duplicate of an earlier comment, to replace a dead link)_

Comment: This sounds like the aesthetic one might find on a planet from the Buck Rogers TV series.